# php $_GET['page'] several pages

Tags: php

```
    if (!$_GET['page'] || preg_match('/\W/', $_GET['page']) || !file_exists('./intl/tpl/tpl_source/' . $_GET['page'] . '.tpl'))
    $_GET['page'] = 'index';
    if ($_GET['page'] && $_GET['page'] != 'index') {
    $smarty->assign("pg_" . $_GET['page'], true);
    $smarty->display($_GET['page'] . ".tpl");
    die();
}
```

This code let me open any page (?page=1, ?page=2 and so on, also it's mean if no page give, open index)

but i need specify which one user can open, so, code should look like:

```
if ($_GET['page'] = '21' || preg_match('/\W/', $_GET['page']) || file_exists('./intl/tpl/tpl_source/' . $_GET['page'] . '.tpl')) {
//my stuff
}
```

In short, i need specify which addresses user can open with  $_GET['page'] (?page=21 ?page=22 and so on).
Sorry if question not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code by using a typecast (for filtering!) and a simpler list of allowed pages:

```
$allowed_pages = array(1, 12, 21, 25, 32);

$page = (int)$_GET["page"]
        and  in_array($page, $allowed_pages)
        and  file_exists("./intl/tpl/tpl_source/$page.tpl")
or $page = "index";

$smarty->assign("pg_$page", true);
$smarty->display("$page.tpl");
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a white list:

```
var $pages = array(
    21 => true,
    22 => true
);
// or
var $pages = array_flip(array(21, 22));
```

and test whether the page is in there:

```
if(isset($pages[$_GET['page']])) {

}
```